# Java group by then collect to list of custom objects

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping, collectors

I have a stream of `Element` from csv file

```java
public class Element {
    private String site;
    private String value;
    private Date date;
...
}
```

and I want to group elements by `site` to a list of `Stat` objects

```java
public class Stat {
    private List<Info> infos;
    private String site;

    public Stat (String site, List<Info> infos) {
...
    }
}

public class Info {
    private String value;
    private Date date;
...
}
```

Here's where I am

```
Map<String, List<Element>> elementsBySite = elements.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Element::getSite));
```

is it possible to re-map my list of `Element` to a list of stat in a single ?

something like

```
Map<String, List<Stats>> statsBySite = elements
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Element::getSite, 
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), 
             // transform each element to Info
             // then create a Stats object with all infos for a given site
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Collectors.mapping` as a downstream to `groupingBy` like:

```
Map<String, List<Stat>> elementsBySite = elements.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Element::getSite,
                Collectors.mapping(e -> convertElementToStat(e),
                        Collectors.toList())));
```

where the signature of the util would be as:

```
Stat convertElementToStat(Element element);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need a Stat object which takes a list of Info as parameter.. First transform Element to Info and get list of Info to create Stat.Should I chain collectors?

Comment: @boizor not really clear from the question then, could you share a minimal code showing the role of the `Info` class there in the transformation that you're talking about?

Comment: just edited my question. An ```Element``` can be mapped to an ```Info```, a ```Stat``` object is a wrapper containing all infos for a given site.